# Организация возвращаемых значений

Tags: c#

Как решаются в проф программировании такие моменты ?

У меня например есть метод, который может вернуть `string` и  в зависимости от этого ответа - есть 4 варианта дальнейшего развития.

А возвращает он такие вещи в зависимости от конструкций `if/else`:

```
return "OK";
return "ERROR|MISSING"
return "ERROR|NOT_SOLVED"
return "ERROR|OTHER"
```

А дальше, другой метод разбирается что с этим делать.

Или нужно использовать там `byte` например для такого или как то иначе вообще ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёшь enum со своими значениями и используешь его.

Answer (score 1):

Как выше отметили, строковые константы можно заменить `enum`'ом.

Однако, это не решает проблемы, когда нужно возвращать различные в зависимости от разных условий=> появляется огромный `case` или `if`, где перебираются различные условия и который тяжело поддерживать.

Если условий **не так много** и в будущем не планируется их расширять, то этот вариант может прокатить.

При большом кол-ве условий, можно попробовать применить шаблон-Состояние или если результат зависит от типа класса, то можно решить проблему через наследование, а затем в каждой конкретной реализации переопределить метод и возвращать 1 из значений.

Comment: Динамика - не не слышал, какие `case` и `if` большие? По вашему, зачем тогда придумали динамическую загрузку и использование типов? Чтобы городить тучу кейсов и ифов? Ради того. чтобы что-то вытянуть, не нужно делать кучи ифов и кейсов, есть большая куча из нее тянуть динамически, какой-то тип.

Comment: @And не понял причем тут динамика и подтягивание типа из кучи.

Comment: А вы вопрос вообще как читаете? `вернуть string и в зависимости от этого ответа`, чтобы это могло значить?

Comment: @And Ну и? Где там слово про создание типов?

Comment: В общем, если у вас есть лучшее предложение, то блесните своими знаниями и дайте отдельный ответ.